# How do I add Xorg/Wayland server arguments through GDM?

Tags: xorg, 17.10, gdm, wayland

[Not important, Ubuntu 17.10]
With LightDM, I was able to modify a file called '50-xserver-command.conf' so I could add the -retro option (just because I could and I wanted it); however, with the new display manager, I am unable to find such a place to add or modify those server arguments. If one does exist, where is it?

Answer (score 0):

The .conf file you're referring to *(I'm assuming it's placed under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`)* wasn't specific to LightDM or GDM, it's being read by XServer when you start a X11 graphical session from a display manager.

So for X11 session nothing changed. In case of Wayland whole XServer is replaced with a compositor, so you have to pass the arguments directly to it. For example for Gnome compositor you can add arguments to the file `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/gnome.desktop` at the line with `Exec=`.

But note that Wayland Compositors would have a whole different set of arguments, so whatever worked for X11 almost definitely won't work for Wayland *(i.e. there might be arguments of analogous functional, but they have to be spelled differently)*. That said, I think the correct way of changing a Wayland compositor behavior is through its settings. E.g. Sway settings are stored at `~/.config/sway/config`.

And make sure you can revert your changes from a pure command line, because if you're going to experiment, you might definitely end up with a broken graphical session, so you'd need to fix it from a TTY.